# Spring Boot Custom Error Page Stack Trace

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, spring-boot, stack-trace

I have found on several locations how to use Spring boot to make a custom error page but I cannot seem to figure out how to make it show a stack trace.

This is what I have:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

            ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/WEB-INF/jsp/app/404.jsp");
            ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/WEB-INF/jsp/app/500.jsp");

            container.addErrorPages(error404Page, error500Page);
        }
    };
}
```

Any ideas how I could figure this out or how to get the stack trace to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't right now using what Spring Boot offers out-of-the-box. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/2371) that I'd like to merge in 1.3 which should give you enough context to figure out the missing bits.