# Get Stack trace from HttpServletRequest in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, stack-trace

I'm currently running a spring boot application.

I am putting this webpage live for multiple people to use. However, this is the first time launching it and I'm unsure if I've worked out all the bugs so I'm trying to find a way to alert myself when something happens.

I have created a custom error controller in Spring. I want this to display a custom error page that just simply tells the user that something is wrong and that we've been made aware of it. This part is working already.

Also with that, I want it to send me an email with the stack trace information. I would love the same page that the default error controller shows, to be sent to me via email. I'm using AWS SES.

Here's my code sample.

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

    if (status != null) {
        int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            return "404";
        }
    }
    
    sesSender.sendErrorEmail("strack trace error");
    return "error";
}
```

I found the following question provided 5 years ago [Spring Boot Custom Error Page Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211434/spring-boot-custom-error-page-stack-trace)
I'm hoping that since then, they've allowed this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot you can use this bean and this method ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(). You will need to import the commons.lang dependency. The method from ExceptionUtils will get you the stack trace you are looking for to send to your email. But this will only work for Serverside Errors. If you want emails sent with a stack trace for front end errors you will need to create your own Dispatcher Servlet and handle it in the DoService Filter

```
@Bean
HandlerExceptionResolver errorHandler() {
    return (request, response, handler, ex) -> {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DispatcherServlet.class);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error/error");
        model.addObject("exceptionType", ex);
        model.addObject("handlerMethod", handler);

        logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getMessage(ex));
        System.out.println("" +
                "\n" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));

        try {
            Utility.sendStackTraceToDeveloper(ex, request, javaMailSender);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return model;
    };
}
```